# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.>com.android.builder

Tags: gradle

> Blockquote

Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

> Blockquote

Here is the **build.gradle** file

```
    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build gradle (project):

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

  allprojects {
     repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
     }
  }
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

From Gradle Console

> `Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:`
>
> `Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define`
>
> `Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcdn;`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there was library confliction with this two libraries:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'
```

so I basically removed

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

since I was going to use onesignal and its library features....  :)